# lowercase or rename all files in a directory on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, uppercase, lowercase, tr, mv

After putting hours into this, I give up, and am asking for help.  This has been answered perfectly in a previous SO question here: [How do I rename all files to lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787029/how-do-i-rename-all-files-to-lowercase)

The trouble is, it does not work on Mac OS X.  So I went about working to redo it so it would work.  Learned a little about strong/weak quoting, which I thought had something to do with it.  For now, I am using strong quoting on everything.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo ""; echo "Start run `basename $0` on `date`";
 echo "Script running from: `pwd`";

 # Change into the directory with the files to rename
 cd /Users/me/Desktop/files
 echo "Working on files in: `pwd`"; echo "";


 # Read in all files from a directory
 for file in *; do
      lowercase_filename=`echo $file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`;
      echo \'$file\' \'$lowercase_filename\';

      mv \'$file\' \'$lowercase_filename\';
      echo "--------------------";

 done
```

Here is what the above script will output when run:

```
 ./renamer.sh 

 Start run renamer.sh on Fri Nov 25 04:35:00 PST 2011
 Script running from: /Users/me/Desktop
 Working on files in: /Users/me/Desktop/files

 'This IS A test TEST.txt' 'this is a test test.txt'
 usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
        mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

For some reason, `mv` doesn't work.  However, what is strange, is if I take the debugging output and manually run this, it will work fine.  So I have a before and and after string of a filename, in this case, the before is the mixed case and the after is the lowercase.  The strings are quoted in single tic marks.  I echo them out just as I would pass them as two args to the `mv` command.

```
'This IS A test TEST.txt' 'this is a test test.txt'
```

The script gives me an error, but if I run these commands by hand:

```
 # "l" is an alias for ls with some args to remove fot files 
 # and other junk I don't want to see.

 me@whitebook:\ $cd files
 me@whitebook:\ $l
 -rw-r--r--+  1 me  staff     0 Nov 25 03:49 This IS A test TEST.txt
 me@whitebook:\ $mv 'This IS A test TEST.txt' 'this is a test test.txt'
 me@whitebook:\ $l
 -rw-r--r--+  1 me  staff     0 Nov 25 03:49 this is a test test.txt
```

As you can see the file was renamed with lowercase just fine to "this is a test test.txt".  If I can `mv` these by hand, then something is happening inside the scripts environment that is getting it confused.  Any idea what that may be?

I should be able to one-line this as the other poster has done, but no matter what I try, it doesn't work for me.

Thanks for any guidance.  I am on Mac OS X, here is some relevant system info...

```
$uname -a
Darwin whitebook.local 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:56:15 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_I386 i386


 $bash --version
 GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
 Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: this is a question better suited for superusers.com, I think.

Comment: Here is my final script in case anyone on Mac OS X Lion or probably lower is looking for this ability.  I plan on adding --convertspaces to change " " to "_" and --uppercase, --sequence ( to add 1. 2. 3. leading the filenames, --aFewMoreIHaventTHoughtOf.

This is just an excerzie in me learning some bash, so it may not be entirely ideal to add these in, but I wanted to learn on something.  This current script can lowercase files and directories, doesn't error when colliding with a directory of the same name, and leave Mac OS X leading dot files ( Invisible ) alone

Comment: You can download the final ( what I feel is working) script from here: http://pastie.org/2943374 copy it to a text file, I call it `lcaser` and chmod u+x on it, then just run it as ./lcaser /path/to/files or if it is in your $PATH that you don't need the ./ and can just use lcaser /path/to/files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
mv "$file" "$lowercase_filename";
```

Comment: Hmmm, that worked! Can you elaborate on what is going on here?  I swear i tried that, though I tried so many different things I can't say for sure.  Thanks.

Comment: @user170579: since you escaped the single-quotes in your version, they weren't treated as functional quotes, just misc characters to be passed to `mv` as part of its arguments.  Thus, `mv` was looking for files named "'This", "IS", "A", "test", "TEST.txt'", "'this" etc.

Comment: Basically, when a variable is in double quotes it gets expanded. `echo '$file'` will output `$file` while `echo "$file"` will output the content of the `$file` variable.

Comment: really useful! here's a one-liner: for f in *; do echo $f; mv $f `echo $f | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:']`; done

Comment: and in bash, you may have to do this to handle filenames with spaces: IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

Comment: In zsh, the following worked for me (slight modification of @nioq’s answer):

`for f in *; do echo $f; mv $f $(echo $f | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:']); done`